# Python: ImportError: cannot import name misc

Tags: python, importerror

I was trying to use the wafo (version 0.1.2) package in python (version 2.7.10) in windows system. I used the installer from this link: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wafo/0.1.2 to install it. Then I tried to test the example script from the user manual:

```
from scipy import *
from pylab import *
import wafo.spectrum.models as wsm
import matplotlib
S = wsm.Torsethaugen(Hm0=6, Tp=8);
S1 = S.tospecdata()
S1.plot()
show()
```

There several errors occurred like "ImportError: No module named lib.six" occurred. But I fixed them by importing the modules needed. Finally I got the following error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<tmp 1>", line 3, in <module>
import wafo.spectrum.models as wsm
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\wafo-0.1.2-py2.7.egg\wafo\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
from . import misc
ImportError: cannot import name misc
```

I tried to google but could not find any remedied. Could anyone give me a solution on this error? Thank you!

Comment: I don't know waft library but it seems like it wasn't properly installed or the dir isn't properly set. Try reinstalling it. As a side note to help test and revert these things, try VirtualEnv

Comment: Version 0.1.2 is from 2010, so I'm not surprised that it doesn't work any more. You could try installing the latest version from the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/wafo-project/pywafo/), which has had some activity recently.

Comment: @DiogoNeves I have tried to reinstall it, but it always ended up in the same error message...

Comment: @Alasdair Yes, I have tried to install the latest version, but like I have said, it ended up in the same error message.

Comment: If there's a problem with the latest version, you could open an issue in Github.

Comment: @Alasdair Thank you for your advice. I have opened an issue and hopefully someone will give me a solution.